# How to add grails to IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I want to learn grails and i want to use IntelliJ IDEA and my professor said that I could connect grails to IntelliJ IDEA  but i dont know how. 
Can you please help me with clear steps on how to do so?

Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Look in to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915199/intellij-idea-9-0-unable-to-select-project-sdk-for-grails-application

Comment: The linked to question is relevant for an older version of Grails, 9.0. I'm having a very similar problem with 10.0, but part of the 9.0 solution doesn't appear to be working, and some of the interface screen-shots are outdated.  **I humbly request that the closers stay their votes for execution**

Answer (score 40):

For an existing project, I always use:

```
grails integrate-with --intellij
```

That'll create .ipr and .iml files for you ready to open up by intellij.

Comment: Perfect answer. I've edited the Grails wiki page to include this "integrate-with". (http://grails.org/IDEA+Integration)

Comment: Surprisingly, this did not work.  I have IDEA 13.1.4 and Grails 2.3.7.  The `integrate-with` command created the project files which Intellij could open, but Intellij gave the error "Failed to run grails command: JDK is not defined".

Comment: @Jason go into your project settings and set your JDK up.  The .ipr that gets created on 2.3.7 defaults to JDK 1.6, which you might not have configured/set up.  Chances are you're using JDK 7 now and need to configure that (hit cmd-; on the mac)

Comment: Yeap, that did it.  I expected that Grails would automatically configure the JDK, and sounds like it does, just not necessarily the right one ;-)

Comment: I am getting these errors now.
`| Error Command not found integrate-with
Did you mean: create-unit-test or generate-all or install-templates?`

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of good pages that can help you:

http://www.grails.org/IDEA+Integration

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/groovy_grails.html

You can create your Grails project using Grails console and then import it into IntelliJ or you can create it directly in IntelliJ, I think it is a matter of preference since both ways work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Create a grails project first through **grails commands**. Then open idea and use the option import a grails project and point to the directory where you did the init of the grails project. Idea will do the rest.

Comment: That would be a round about way of doing it.

Comment: @Doc_180. You are right! I just found that it worked the best for me instead of trying to create a project through Idea.

Comment: You can create file .project by hand, then try open it by IntelliJ. Actually, IntelliJ looks for this file to open the project, though it doesn't really need the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a windows user, you might be disappointed , as at the moment (may 2016), grails support is removed from windows environment, as can be verified from here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/10/intellij-idea-15-eap-supports-grails-3/
As quoted "We drop the Grails tool window. We’re sorry about it"

So, just download the latest IntelliJ IDEA 15 EAP if you are facing an issue