# Run first Grails App with intellij IDEA with 12.0

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I am new to grails and I have never used intellij IDEA. Now I want to run a normal app in grails with it. So what should I install when install intellij ? only tomcat or anything else ? please inform me as soon as possible ?

Comment: You can explore from the previous posted thread. [Check This Same Thread][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5290490/2115255

Comment: Ultimate or Community edition?

Comment: I don't know about Community edition, but Ultimate edition can open/edit/run Grails app without any extra steps, you just need to download Grails SDK to somewhere

Comment: See the IntelliJ IDEA help section about their Grails support: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/grails.html