# Grails App using IntelliJ Ultimate: Unable to resolve class when building solution

Tags: java, spring, grails, intellij-idea, groovy

I am trying to get a Grails app up and running using **IntelliJ Ultimate**.  I am using the following SDKs and Frameworks:

1) **Java JDK 1.7**

2) **Grails 2.2.4**

3) **Spring Framework**

This is an existing Grails Application that is using these libraries.  I have cloned the project from a remote repo and imported it into IntelliJ Ultimate.  When I try to build this app, I keep getting the following errors from within my groovy projects:

`Groovyc: unable to resolve class com.company.domain.business`

I am new to using Grails and IntelliJ, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried integrating project with intellij with `grails integrate-with --intellij` [https://stackoverflow.com/a/5291132/2224598]? Then, rather than importing project, you can open generated `.ipr` file. Intellij should work out some things for you.

Comment: there is a webinar recorded by grails framework co-founder Jeff Scott Brown titled Why IntelliJ IDEA is the Premier IDE for Grails 3, he gave an overview of the Grails 3 support in IntelliJ IDEA (both Community and Ultimate) although I do not know if this webinar answers your question could have some reference of interest, I share the link https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/07/webinar-recording-why-intellij-idea-is-the-premier-ide-for-grails-3/

Comment: @suricatta I tried running `grails integrate-with --intellij` and it added 3 files, an `.iml`, `.ipr` and `.iws file.  When I try to build my project, I get the following error `Cannot compile Groovy files: no Groovy library is defind for module`.

Comment: @JeffP. I think you have to go to _File -> Project Structure_ and select directory where you installed grails in _Project SDK_ section on top.