# Cannot Build Grails App Using Java JDK 1.7 and Grails 2.2.4

Tags: spring, grails, intellij-idea

This is connected to this question I asked last week: [Grails App using IntelliJ Ultimate: Unable to resolve class when building solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718160/grails-app-using-intellij-ultimate-unable-to-resolve-class-when-building-soluti)

I am trying to import a Grails App that is using Java **JDK 1.7** and **Grails 2.2.4**.  I'm currently using the IntelliJ Ultimate IDE.  I have configured my project to use these libraries.

Now when I try to build this project, I get a few errors:

`Caused by org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transacationManager'`

I'm also getting 3 more errors similar to the one above for `transactionManager`, `sessionFactory` and `lobHandlerDetector`.

I also modified the file `DataSource.groovy` with my database credentials and I'm also getting Database connection errors:
`Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData, nested exception in org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory`

`Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.  Attempted reconnect 3  times. Giving up.`

'Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

I'm really stumped by why I can't get this app to run on IntelliJ Ultimate, even with the project configured to use the libraries I mentioned above.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems the `mysql` service is not running that could prevent the connection pool from instantiating.

Comment: @Parth My app is now running since the issue was I wasn't connecting to my local MySql server within the `DataSource.groovy` file.  I just had to make sure I was connecting to where I had it set up on localhost.  Thanks for the help!