# IntelliJ 12.0.1 - Grails 2.3.X Distribution in specified path is broken

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I am struggling to configure **grails 2.3.X** in **IntelliJ idea 12.0.1**. **Grails 2.2.X** is configured successfully.

Grails 2.3.2 is working properly from terminal. I can compile, test, run my application. But while trying to configure it in IntelliJ so that dependencies get resolved,  I get the IntelliJ shouting straight to me(as pictured below).

> Looks like Grails Distribution in specified path is broken. Cannot 
>   determinate version.

[image: Grails dist]

What I see is changes in `grails-2.3.x/dist/` to earlier version's `grails-2.2.x/dist/`.

**Is this because there's no support for newer version(2.3.x) of grails in IntelliJ 12 or what ?**

I want nothing else but my **application (jar) dependencies** to be resolved in the IDE.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are running the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA - v12.1.6. There was a "Grails 2.3.0 not working" [bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114681) fixed in 12.1.6.

You may also want to take a look at the [Grails SDK is not configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887932/intellij-11-grails-sdk-is-not-configured) question. One of the IntelliJ IDEA developers has a detailed answer in that question that may help.

Also, this [thread](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/283964) on the IntelliJ IDEA forum may be useful.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA v12.0.1. I will check if updating IntelliJ to 12.1.6 fixes the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### For Information

**to reload the dependencies** in IntelliJ 12.1.6 , following path works fine.

```
      Tools
           -> Grails
               -> Synchronize Grails settings
```