# How to add a new Grails SDK to IntelliJ 11.1

Tags: grails, module, intellij-idea, addition, upgrade

Ok Guys, after wrestling with trying to upgrade the grails version for an existing application in intelliJ, I decided to see if I could just make a new grails application with a new SDK. Turns out this won't even work. So here's what I did:

[The steps I took](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwdJZ.jpg)

Anyone that has had a similar experience got any ideas?

Comment: Not a solution, but we've had trouble with this before - our solution was to use GVM (groovy environment manager) which will update and change the current grails version by swapping in/out different versions. This way, IntelliJ always points to the same directory for the SDK, but you can change it around whenever you'd like.  http://gvmtool.net. Sorry, just noticed you're probably on windows, if so, try Gravy (https://github.com/enterprise-grails/gravy)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've tried using gravy and looking at the script it's just an easy way for setting GRAILS_HOME environment variable which intelliJ doesn't seem to look at. When I set GRAILS_HOME to 2.3.3, change the application.properties file to 2.3.3 and run an app, it says grails_home is set to 1.3.7. So intelliJ seems to have it's own internal pointer which I can't seem to change.

Comment: I see, perhaps the answer to this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887932/intellij-11-grails-sdk-is-not-configured

Comment: Steps you've shown looks good, works for me. Make sure that directory 2.3.3 really have this version. Also try to remove existing project (.idea, .iml, .ipr) and create project again

Comment: @bschipp Yep I've tried adding it to the global libraries too, it doesn't seem to find and index the classes like it does for 1.3.7: ([See Here](http://imgur.com/a/lSK1n)). By what I've seen on some other forums is that it's a potential bug with older intelliJ versions. I'll see if an upgrade resolves the issue. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem and the only fix I've found is to use newer version of IntelliJ Idea IDE - 12.04.

Comment: After searching for a solution all yesterday it seems to be the best thing to do. A thread on the grails forum indicated that it's a potential bug with older versions of intelliJ. Thanks for responding